# Create folders in directory and save files in the new folders with for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, working-directory

I have fairly complicated code for creating a heatmap, but a simple objective. Using a for-loop, instead of R printing all heatmap files to a single folder, how would I tell it to create a new folder each time I tell it to also print a heatmap, and put the heatmap that matches the folder name inside that newly created folder (Print map "A" to PNG and map "A" goes in folder "A", etc...)?

The following code goes through all unique names in the object "splist", creates a heatmap for each name, then prints all heatmaps to the same folder. How would I correct it so that each heatmap file is put in it's own folder? If my code doesn't work, any heatmap style will do with any example data, I just hope to create separate folders for each file using the for-loop I've made.

```
GetMatrix=function(data,spToSum) {
 newdat<-filter(data,common_name %in% spToSum)
 matrixdat<-dcast(newdat, site ~ year_season, value.var="num", fun.aggregate = sum)
 matrixdat$site <- as.character(matrixdat$site)
 matrixdat <- matrixdat[order(nchar(matrixdat$site), matrixdat$site)]
 matrixdat <- matrixdat %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="site") # col to row names
 as.matrix(matrixdat)
}

PlotHeatMap <- Heatmap(as.matrix(round(log(data+1), digits = 1)),
               cluster_rows = FALSE,
               cluster_columns = FALSE,
               na_col = "black",
               column_title = "Year/Season",
               row_title = "Site",
               heatmap_legend_param = list(title = "ln(x+1)"))

dataList<-list()
filenameVal<-paste0(1:length(splist),splist," - NotClustered.png")
doClusterVal<-FALSE

setwd('C:/...')

# Prints the maps
for(run in 1:length(splist)) {
 dataList[[run]]<-GetMatrix(filter(dat,CYR>=2005),splist[run])  
 PlotHeatMap(data=dataList[[run]],splist[run],fileName=filenameVal[run],doCluster=doClusterVal)
 dir.create(file.path(splist[run]), recursive = TRUE)
 print(paste(run,splist[run]))
}

# common_name = fish/shrimp/crab name
# num = count
# site = location #
# CYR = calendar year
# Season = wet/dry season
```

Random selection of 10 rows of data:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(common_name = c("Mojarra spp", "Chub spp", "Glass Shrimp", 
"Lined Sole", "Pink Shrimp", "Iridescent Shrimp", "Giant Decorator crab", 
"Longnose Spider Crab", "Pearl Blenny", "Banded Killifish"), 
    num = c(4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), site = c(4L, 
    1L, 47L, 5L, 10L, 18L, 22L, 3L, 42L, 19L), CYR = c(2017L, 
    2012L, 2013L, 2019L, 2008L, 2019L, 2009L, 2009L, 2014L, 2015L
    ), Season = c("WET", "WET", "WET", "DRY", "WET", "DRY", "DRY", 
    "DRY", "DRY", "DRY"), year_season = c("2017_WET", "2012_WET", 
    "2013_WET", "2019_DRY", "2008_WET", "2019_DRY", "2009_DRY", 
    "2009_DRY", "2014_DRY", "2015_DRY")), row.names = c(175919L, 
114959L, 124359L, 204205L, 53943L, 207868L, 61123L, 64762L, 130625L, 
148966L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In your code, is `PlotHeatMap` supposed to be a function that takes a filename as argument? because the `PlotHeatMap <- `-line does not look like that. Also, your code is not  reproducible, e.g. who is `splist`?

Comment: Yes, I apologize for not making it not reproducible - the for loop to drop species without enough observations and set rules for clustering would have taken up 500+ lines of code. splist is all the unique common_names (n=154). So, for every species in the dataframe it makes a matrix, plots a heatmap from the matrix, and should print a png in its own folder.

Comment: "PlotHeatMap" is the code for running the heatmap.

Comment: But `PlotHeatMap` is used like a function inside the for loop. But it is not a not a function in the `PlotHeatMap <- ...`-line. I do not understand how the `PlotHeatMap`-line inside the for loop should work unless you have a function definition elsewhere.

Comment: Also it would be nice to know the package that `Heatmap` is from

Comment: Furthermore, why do you want to generate the filenames before and not inside the loop? You would just create a directory and the filename from `run`.

Comment: @clemenskuehn, yes it should be defined as a function here as it is in my code, but it's many lines of code that I thought would take up too much space here. It decides what to do with data that isn't sufficient for clustered heatmaps.

Comment: library(ComplexHeatmap) from Bioconductor

Comment: The order should go: Make a matrix for each unique "common_name", if making an unclustered heatmap use the matrix from step 1 and make the map for each common_name, then make folders for each common_name and put the respective maps inside those folders.

Comment: I can re-make my question with all the original code if this isn't enough to work with.

Comment: maybe we really don't need everything around it. I do not really see your problem. I would do something like `for(run in common_names){ prepare data, create plot, generate foldername, create folder, save plot to folder}` and for creating the folder as a subfolder of some sensible starting folder you sue paste0.

Comment: Going any further before knowing anything about `PlotHeatMap` would be quite cumbersome. You seem to give it some filename. So it prints the Heatmap to a file already? why don't you create the folder before and give the folder/filename to the function?
Maybe you should rethink your question and ask it in a different way?

Comment: Ya the "save plot to folder" is my main issue. The heatmap file names all look something like this: "1. Tuna", "2. Flounder"..etc. (the number corresponds to how abundant the name/species is in the dataframe - tuna is most abundant, for example) and the folders would have the same name. I'll repost the question, thanks for the help!